# Unminify AS3 code tools

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, unminify

I have bought a flash template which contains as3 code. This code is minified or simply saying whole code is in one line.

Can anyone plz share the tools to unminify the flash as3 code? Internet is full of tools to unminify css or JS tools but I can't find as3 related stuff.

Plz help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a shot in the dark here:
Select all. Click the 'Auto format' button.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Just one more thing, do you know how to remove comments starting from "//". This really creates problem sometimes.

Comment: No, I'm afraid you'll just have to search for each instance of "//" and remove them manually.

Answer (score 0):

I want to start up front by saying that lolspeak is inappropriate for these types of venues and even more annoying when I'm already in a bad mood. However, I'm going to overlooks that and point out that you can probably use [Flex Formatter](http://gskinner.com/blog/archives/2009/12/indispensable_p.html) to do this.